# Calculate Highest value of Serialized and non-Serialized values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to find the highest value of a mix of serialized and non-serialized values via Google Sheets.  Ideally, I'd prefer a single-cell formula but multiple cells is fine.

```
NormalValue1 = 10
Serialied1   = 30
NormalValue2 = 60
Serialized1  = 10
Serialized2  = 5
Serialized2  = 5
```

The expected results would be:

```
Serialized1 = 40 (30+10)
Serialized2 = 10 (5+5)

NormalValue Highest = 60
Serialized  Highest = 40 (Serialized1 at 30+10)
Final result:       = 60
```

Here's an example of what I'd ultimately like to have.
[Example table from Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL9pC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your labels and numbers are in A11:B19, this should produce the final max:

`=ArrayFormula(MAX(SUMIF(A11:A19,A11:A19,B11:B19)))`

Essentially, this sums by same label and then returns the max among all label totals.

This would do the same thing:

`=MAX(QUERY({A11:B19},"Select SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1"))`

Comment: I used the first formula you provided and it worked perfectly!  Never played with an ArrayFormula before.  Very interesting.  